# How to make changes to the image

Tags: html, css

I have created an image in html with the img tag as specified below under section and provided div class as picture-1-image. I am trying to track the image to css to fit the image on the screen but seems like the CSS is not able to track the image based on the particular class. Please help me out here

```
<body class = "new-homepage-template-landing-tc1-page", id="page-new-homepage">
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7-mid-banner">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="Homepage.html">
                            <img src="" alt="Logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul type ="None">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Signin</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="picture-1-image">
            <img src="./happy-female-doctor-giving-high-fie-little-boy-who-came-with-father-hospital.jpg", 
            alt="child-giving-high-five-to-a-doctor", class = "picture-image">
        </div>
    </section>
    
    
</body>
```

"The image is mentioned under section, div class = "picture-1-image" under img tag. Iam trying to get the CSS selector as below"

```
 .picture-image{
    background-size: cover;
}
```

so that I could fit the image in the screen but it is not able to.

I have added the image as to what I am getting. I need this image to be fit to screen. How can I do that?

Comment: src="happy-female-doctor-giving-high-fie-little-boy-who-came-with-father-hospital.jpg" cross browser does not use relative path / or ./ to indicate same folder in html elements for resources.